# What difference it makes to initialize a variable before allocating it dynamically

Tags: c, malloc

Please see the code:

```c
struct something* s = malloc(sizeof(struct something));
s = NULL;
```

Here I am allocating memory to `s` dynamically, while defining. And then initializing it to `NULL`.

```c
struct something* s = NULL;
s = malloc(sizeof(struct something));
```

Here I am defining and initializing it with NULL value and then allocating (changing) it's memory allocation to dynamic memory.

What else differences it make? Also please correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

And which one is a bad practice, if any?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Here I am allocating memory to s dynamically while defining and then initializing it to NULL.

No, you're not. By doing

```
struct something* s = malloc(sizeof(struct something));
s = NULL;
```

You're essentially discarding the only pointer to the memory (by setting it to `NULL`) allocated by `malloc()`. You're leaking memory here.

If you want to *initalize* the allocated memory to, say, 0, you've to do something like

```
memset(s,0, sizeof(struct something));
```

However, your second snippet

```
struct something* s = NULL;          //define and initialize to NULL
s = malloc(sizeof(struct something));  //allocate memory
```

is perfectly valid and the correct approach. Here you're

- defining `s` and assigning `NULL`, to prevent uninitalize use.
- allocating memory to `s` before use

> Don't forget to `free()` the memeory after use.

Perfect !!

Comment: or may be the second thing which I am doing is correct.

Comment: @AnilBhaskar Only if there is code between the two lines. Otherwise, the one liner is better: `struct something* s = malloc(sizeof(struct something));`

Comment: @juanchopanza Absolutely. Just thought of mentioning, `s = NULL;` should not be done unless 1) after calling `free(s)` 2) having a copy of `s`. Please correct me sir if i'm wrong.

Comment: BTW in `struct something* s = NULL; s = malloc(sizeof(struct something));`, the first part is clearly a noop since you first set the pointer to be null, and immediately give it another value. Just like `int i = 1; i = 2;` !

Comment: thanks @SouravGhosh, yes correct, just playing by breaking it.

Comment: @SergeBallesta only if these two lines appear in succession. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This create a reference to somewhere in the memory.

```
struct something* s = malloc(sizeof(struct something));
```

You are destroying the reference.

```
s = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problam in your first code is that your getting an adress if malloc is succefull, but deleting it right after - by asigning null instead of the adress you got.

as said before - your second aproach is better.
make sure that you handle a case of unsuccessful memory allocation - because if it fails you will get unexpected behavior.
about uninitialized pointers - it is recommended that you will initilized your data right after the memory allocation (and the allocation success checking).

E.G:

```
 struct something* s = malloc(sizeof(struct something))
 //alocating memory
 if(!s) return OUT_OF_MEMORY;
 //memory allocation failed, returning a proper messege
 /*DO SOMTHING WITH s*/
```